# Formatting the code on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Can someone help me with formatting the question before posting it here. The editor is not allowing me to post my code. I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?  There are options for formatting text in the editor; for quotes, code, links, etc.  Are you getting an error of some sort?  Or just no formatting?

Comment: There's an orange box at the upper right corner of the edit box that has a white `?`. Click that box for editing help.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the markdown help page - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

That should give you enough information to start, but you can always edit your question after posting it if you're not happy with the format.